# Extracting URLs using regex in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've taken inspiration from the example show in the following URL [csharp-online](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Extracting_Groups_from_a_MatchCollection)
and intended to retrieve all the URLs from this page [alexa](http://www.alexa.com/topsites/category/Top/Society/History/By_Topic/Science/Engineering_and_Technology)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ExtractingUrls
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            const string url = "http://www.alexa.com/topsites/category/Top/Society/History/By_Topic/Science/Engineering_and_Technology";
            string source = client.DownloadString(url);
            //Console.WriteLine(Getvals(source));
            string matchPattern =
                    @"<a.rel=""nofollow"".style=""font-size:0.8em;"".href=[""'](?<url>[^""^']+[.]*)[""'].class=""offsite"".*>(?<name>[^<]+[.]*)</a>";
            foreach (Hashtable grouping in ExtractGroupings(source, matchPattern, true))
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry DE in grouping)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value = " + DE.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
            // End.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static ArrayList ExtractGroupings(string source, string matchPattern, bool wantInitialMatch)
        {
            ArrayList keyedMatches = new ArrayList();
            int startingElement = 1;
            if (wantInitialMatch)
            {
                startingElement = 0;
            }
            Regex RE = new Regex(matchPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            MatchCollection theMatches = RE.Matches(source);
            foreach (Match m in theMatches)
            {
                Hashtable groupings = new Hashtable();
                for (int counter = startingElement; counter < m.Groups.Count; counter++)
                {
                    // If we had just returned the MatchCollection directly, the
                    // GroupNameFromNumber method would not be available to use
                    groupings.Add(RE.GroupNameFromNumber(counter),
                    m.Groups[counter]);
                }
                keyedMatches.Add(groupings);
            }
            return (keyedMatches);
        }
    }
}
```

But here I face a problem, when I'm executing each URL is being displayed thrice, That's first the whole anchor tag is getting displayed, next the URL is being displayed twice. can anyone suggest me where should I correct so that I can have each URL displayed exactly once.

Comment: **DO _NOT_ PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions!** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @SLacks: "it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your regex, you have two groupings, and the entire match. If I'm reading it correctly, you should only want the URL portion of the matches, which is the second of the 3 groupings....

instead of this:

```
for (int counter = startingElement; counter < m.Groups.Count; counter++)
            {
                // If we had just returned the MatchCollection directly, the
                // GroupNameFromNumber method would not be available to use
                groupings.Add(RE.GroupNameFromNumber(counter),
                m.Groups[counter]);
            }
```

don't you want this?:

```
groupings.Add(RE.GroupNameFromNumber(1),m.Groups[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to parse HTML. I think it will make your problem much easier to solve.

Here's one way to do it:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://www.alexa.com/topsites/category/Top/Society/History/By_Topic/Science/Engineering_and_Technology";
string source = client.DownloadString(url);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href and @rel='nofollow']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int startingElement = 1;
if (wantInitialMatch)
{
startingElement = 0;
}
```

...

```
for (int counter = startingElement; counter < m.Groups.Count; counter++)
{
// If we had just returned the MatchCollection directly, the
// GroupNameFromNumber method would not be available to use
    groupings.Add(RE.GroupNameFromNumber(counter),
    .Groups[counter]);
}
```

Your passing `wantInitialMatch = true`, so your for loop is returning:

```
.Groups[0] //entire match
.Groups[1] //(?<url>[^""^']+[.]*) href part
.Groups[2] //(?<name>[^<]+[.]*) link text
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look of this:
http://bouncetadiss.blogspot.com/2008/02/parsing-uri-url-in-c-and-vbnet.html